# Video and Audio out of sync on youtube - Firefox

Tags: sound, firefox, video

This is about my laptop Lenovo G50. The title says it - sometimes playback stops for half a second and then resumes throwing the entire video out of sync. This is a problem I faced on 16.04 and am currently facing on Ubuntu 18 too. I've downloaded the recent updates and this problem still persists. What is confusing me more is that my desktop PC has no issues (same i3 processor and 2 gigs of ram more than my laptop which is 4 gigs). Has anybody experienced or found a solution to this?